# Spring Boot Migration 1.5.7 to 2.4.5: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap, wsdl

I recently migrated from Spring Boot 1.5.7 to 2.4.5 and somehow my integration tests (all eight) are failing:

### Config Details

### gradle.wrapper gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: "jacoco"
    apply plugin: 'no.nils.wsdl2java'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

    group 'com.xxx.abc'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    jar {
        baseName = 'abcd-service'
    }

    buildscript {
        ext {
            springBootVersion = '2.4.5'
            springWSVersion = '2.4.0.RELEASE'
            springSecurity = '5.1.6.RELEASE'
            slf4jVersion = '1.7.30'
            pivotalConfigClientVersion = '3.0.1.RELEASE'
            dependencyManagementPluginVersion = '1.0.11.RELEASE'
            httpclientVersion = '4.5.2'
            lombokVersion = '1.18.20'
            swaggerVersion = '2.9.2'
    //        swaggerVersion = '3.0.0'
            mockserverVersion = '5.5.1'
    //        mockserverVersion = '3.10.2'
            springVersion = '5.11.2.RELEASE'
            loggingUtilVersion = '0.1.29'
            junitVersion = '4.12'
        }
        repositories {
            maven {
                url '<<artifactoryURL>>'
                metadataSources {
                    mavenPom()
                    artifact()
                }
            }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    //        classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:$dependencyManagementPluginVersion"
            classpath('no.nils:wsdl2java:0.10')
        }
    }

    // Lets extend the resources of test to avoid duplication in integration test resources
    configurations {
        integrationTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
        integrationTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
    }

    //wsdl2java {
    //    wsdlsToGenerate = [
    //            ['-xjc-Xlombok',
    //             '-xjc-Xbg',
    //             '-xjc-Xvalue-constructor',
    //             '-mark-generated',
    //             '-autoNameResolution',
    //             '-b', "$projectDir/src/main/resources/binding.xjb",
    //             "$projectDir/src/main/resources/wsdl/abc-v1.wsdl"],
    //            ['-xjc-Xlombok',
    //             '-xjc-Xbg',
    //             '-xjc-Xvalue-constructor',
    //             '-mark-generated',
    //             '-autoNameResolution',
    //             '-b', "$projectDir/src/main/resources/binding.xjb",
    //             "$projectDir/src/main/resources/wsdl/xvz_v13.wsdl"]
    //    ]
    //    generatedWsdlDir = file("$projectDir/src/generated-sources")
    //    wsdlDir = file("$projectDir/src/main/resources/wsdl")
    //}

    def baseSvnUrl = "http://abcdef.com/svn/wsdls"

    //default wsdl directory path
    def wsdlDirPath = file(new File('src/main/resources/wsdl'))

    // abc soap client
    def abcUrl = "$baseSvnUrl/abc/abc-v1.wsdl"
    def abcWsdl = file("$wsdlDirPath/abc-v1.wsdl")
    def abcWsdlSafe = "wsdl/abc-v1.wsdl"

    def xyzUrl = "$baseSvnUrl/pqr/xyz-v13.wsdl"
    def xyzWsdl = file("$wsdlDirPath/xyz_v13.wsdl")
    def xyzSafe = "wsdl/xyz_v13.wsdl"

    //download wsdl file

    def downloadWsdl(fileName, wsdlUrl) {
        def f = new File(fileName)
        if (!f.exists()) {
            new URL(wsdlUrl).withInputStream{ i -> f.withOutputStream{ it << i }}
        }
    }

    def createWsdlToGenerateArray(wsdlLocation, wsdlUrl) {
        //xjb Binding location
        def xjbBindingPath = "src/main/resources/binding.xjb"
        return ['-xjc-Xlombok', '-xjc-Xbg', '-xjc-Xvalue-constructor', '-mark-generated', '-autoNameResolution',
                '-b', "$xjbBindingPath", '-wsdlLocation', wsdlLocation, wsdlUrl]
    }
    wsdl2java {
        repositories {
            maven {
                url '<<artifactoryUrl>>'
            }
        }
        generatedWsdlDir = file(new File("src/main/generated-sources"))
        wsdlDir = file("$wsdlDirPath")

        // downloading ABC wsdl file
        downloadWsdl("$abcWsdl", "$abcUrl")
        downloadWsdl("$xyzWsdl", "$xyzUrl")

        // just make a copy of createWsdlToGenerateArray to build another soap service code generation
        wsdlsToGenerate = [
                createWsdlToGenerateArray("$abcWsdlSafe", "$abcUrl"),
                createWsdlToGenerateArray("$xycSafe", "$xyzUrl")
        ]
    }
    // my project integrationTest directories
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += "$projectDir/src/generated-sources"
        integrationTest {
            java {
                compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
                runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
                srcDir file('src/integrationTest/java')
            }
            resources.srcDir file('src/integrationTest/resources')
        }
    }

    //integrationTest task
    task integrationTest(type: Test) {
        testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDirs
        classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            url '<<artifactoryUrl>>'
        }
    }

    apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"

    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2020.0.2'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile(
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}",
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter",
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator",
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa",
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc",
            "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config",
            "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap",
                "io.pivotal.spring.cloud:spring-cloud-services-starter-config-client:$pivotalConfigClientVersion",
                "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0.1",
            "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:${slf4jVersion}",
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration:${springBootVersion}",
    //        "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}",
    //        "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:${springBootVersion}",
            'com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc8-production:21.1.0.0',
    //        "com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc7:12.1.0.2",
            "org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:${springWSVersion}",
            "org.springframework.security:spring-security-config",
            "org.springframework.security:spring-security-core",
            "com.xxx.abc:common-logging-util:$loggingUtilVersion",
            "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}",
            "io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:${swaggerVersion}",
            "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:${swaggerVersion}",
            'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8.1',
            "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:${httpclientVersion}",

            'org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-runtime:1.11.1',
    //        'com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.0.0',
            "org.mock-server:mockserver-integration-testing:$mockserverVersion",
            "org.mock-server:mockserver-netty:$mockserverVersion",
    //        'it.yobibit:jaxb-lombok-plugin:1.0.0',
    //        "org.mockito:mockito-core:$mockitoVersion"
        )

        annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
        testAnnotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"

    //    compile group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.9.9'
        compile(files(wsdl2java.generatedWsdlDir).builtBy(wsdl2java))
        wsdl2java 'org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-runtime:1.11.1'
        wsdl2java 'org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics:1.11.1'
        wsdl2java 'de.plushnikov.xjc:xjc-lombok-plugin:1.0'
        wsdl2java 'org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-value-constructor:3.0'

        testCompile(
                "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:${springBootVersion}",
    //            "com.jayway.restassured:rest-assured:2.5.0",
    //            'com.jayway.restassured:json-schema-validator:2.5.0',
    //            'com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.0.0',
                "org.mock-server:mockserver-integration-testing:${mockserverVersion}",
                "org.mock-server:mockserver-netty:${mockserverVersion}",
                "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
        )

        check.dependsOn integrationTest
        integrationTest.mustRunAfter test
    }

    jacoco {
        toolVersion = "0.8.6"
    }

    test { finalizedBy jacocoTestReport }

    jacocoTestReport {
        reports {
            xml.enabled false
            csv.enabled false
            html.enabled true
            html.destination file("${buildDir}/jacocoHtml")
    //        html.destination "${buildDir}/jacocoHtml"
        }
        afterEvaluate {
            getClassDirectories().setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.collect{
                fileTree(dir: it, exclude: ['**/model/**'])
            }))
        }
    }

    //task jarWithSources(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    //    classifier = 'source'
    //    from sourceSets.main.allSource
    //    from sourceSets.main.output
    //}

    task listAllDependencies(type: DependencyReportTask) {}
    defaultTasks 'clean', 'build'
```

### Annotations on all integrationTest classes (same for all failing)

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
```

Finally Exception in all the failing test cases when I run ./gradlew clean build

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:43)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:412)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:774)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:123)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:159)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is java.util.NoSuchElementException: Unable to get attribute value for missing annotation
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:212)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:203)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:97)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:86)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:259)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:233)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5161)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is java.util.NoSuchElementException: Unable to get attribute value for missing annotation
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    ... 105 more
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Unable to get attribute value for missing annotation
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.MissingMergedAnnotation.getAttributeValue(MissingMergedAnnotation.java:160)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AbstractMergedAnnotation.getRequiredAttributeValue(AbstractMergedAnnotation.java:217)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AbstractMergedAnnotation.getString(AbstractMergedAnnotation.java:139)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer$EndpointBean.<init>(EndpointDiscoverer.java:414)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.createEndpointBean(EndpointDiscoverer.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.createEndpointBeans(EndpointDiscoverer.java:134)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.discoverEndpoints(EndpointDiscoverer.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.getEndpoints(EndpointDiscoverer.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.servletEndpointRegistrar(ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 106 more
```

Any help in this regard shall be appreciated.

Comment: Eight (8) integration test failures - that's a lot. Consider editing your question to focus on one of those test failures. Describing what you have tried to correct that test failure could also be helpful.

Comment: I mentioned eight just to inform that all the integration tests are failing with same exception and I have mentioned the complete above. 

I googled a lot before posting this question and tried a couple of libraries suggested by people like adding webflux with web, jpa and a few more dependencies, but nothing helped. Some how servletendpoint bean is not getting loaded, Initially I though that it has something to do with spring boot version 2.4.5 but lowering the versions or incrementing the versions also didn’t help.

Comment: Something has gone wrong in Spring Boot’s discovery of actuator endpoints but I can’t tell if that’s due to a bug in your application, in Spring Boot itself, or one of your application’s dependencies. Can you strip things back to remove anything that’s not needed to reproduce the problem and share the resulting [minimal, reproducible, example](/help/mcve)?

Comment: Alternatively, you could try debugging your app with a breakpoint on [line 414 of EndpointDiscoverer.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/7caf238a90fbb67a23666ba6ed3384011af01378/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/annotation/EndpointDiscoverer.java#L414) to identify the faulty endpoint `beanType`.

Comment: Thanks @AndyWilkinson with the minimal approach and removing all dependencies and adding one by one as needed, I am able to resolve those eight failing tests but now only one is failing with other exception mentioned below `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
`